# Android linearLayout understanding

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I Want to create an android activity which will have few vertical stripes, here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#CCCCCC" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see the upper stripe is 50 dp and the bottom stripe is 250 dp. the problem is that I am seeing only one stripe, here is what I see:
[image]

I see only one stripe.

How should I do this right?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your parent `LinearLayout`'s `orientation` attribute is `horizontal`. If you make its orientation (`android:orientation`) set to `vertical` the problem should be fixed.

Please post your whole layout file.

Answer (score 1):

LinearLayout's orientation attribute decides how its child views are going to be drawn: one below the other(vertical) or one besides the other (horizontal).
You can find LinearLayout example [here](https://github.com/asnehal/Layouts.git)